# Getting this error in django "login() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user' "

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I am a new Django user and I just created a registration and login system for my website in Django 1.11. I am struck when I go to login section of my website. I get the error as mentioned "login() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'" and I can't figure out what's wrong with the login function and the variable 'user'. Kindly help me. Thanks in advance. Here is my code:

**urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth import login


app_name='one'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^games$',views.games,name='games'),
    url(r'^others$',views.others,name='others'),
    url(r'^about$',views.about,name='about'),
    url(r'^upload$',views.UploadFile.as_view(),name='upload'),
    url(r'^register$',views.UserFormView.as_view(),name='register'),
    url(r'^login/$', login, name='login'),

]
```

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from .models import file
from django.views.generic import View
from .forms import user_form
class UserFormView(View):
    form_class = user_form
    template_name = 'one/register_form.html'

    def get (self,request):
        form = self.form_class(None)
        return render(request,self.template_name,{'form':form})

    def post (self,request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit = False)
            username= form.cleaned_data['username']
            password= form.cleaned_data['password']
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()

            user= authenticate(username=username, password=password)

            if user is not None:

                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    redirect('one:profile')

        return render(request,self.template_name,{'form':form})
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You’ve got the import wrong. You need to import the `login` view:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import login
```

At the moment you have imported the [`login`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.login) function that actually logs the user in.

The `login` view you are using is deprecated in Django 1.11. You can switch to the new class-based [`LoginView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView):

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

url(r'^login/$', LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
```

Comment: from django.contrib.auth.view import LoginView I added this line but I am getting an error

Comment: No module named 'django.contrib.auth.view'

Comment: That's because it's view**s**, not views.